# several buttons that should be clicked in one page and on another page it display the number of clicks in each button

Tags: java, android

i have a page that have several buttons  and  the role of this page is to click the buttons several times and there should be counter I saved  the number of each button clicked in its shared preference . My problems are :
- I need this button to be clicked  at every click  a new activity will open and at the same time number of clicks will be saved in its shared preference
- I need the counter that counts the number of clicks to be zero after the user close the application

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: I need this button when clicked :at every click a new activity will open and at the same time number of clicks will be saved in its shared preference - I need the counter that counts the number of clicks to be zero after the user close the application

Comment: SO isn't a place that codes for you, make an attempt and come back with a real problem when you get an error or have trouble after actually trying to code the solution.

Comment: So set it to 0 when application exits or starts

Answer (score 0):

To create a new activity on button click use this:

```
Intent i = new Intent("name_of_intento_declared_in_manifest");
startActivity(i);
```

When you start your mainactivity you have to set a new count variable as static and initialize to 0 into onCreate method.
Then into your new activity import count variable from mainactivity and increase it

Hope this will help you

Comment: hello  I got your point but please  I need a code that has the following role : when clicking on  a button it saves the number of clicks in a shared preference and at the same time it opens another activity and these number of clicks appeared in another extra activity is it clear?

Comment: But if you click on button and it start a new activity, how can you increase your count value clicking button?

Comment: so is it possible to view this activity as toast or dialog without affecting the number of clicks?

Comment: You can view count number into a toast for each button click printing count value into toast everytime you click it